# Python - Error in a 'for' loop to achive maximum value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

That's the first part of the code:

```
handle = open('mbox-short.txt')

sender = dict()
words = list()

for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        words = line.split()
        email = words[1]
        sender[email] = sender.get(email, 0) + 1
```

It returns this dictionary (sender):

```
sender = {'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 2, 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 3, 'zqian@umich.edu': 4}
```

That's the second part of the code:

```
for key in sender:

    if max == None:
        value = int(sender[key])
        max = value

    else:
        value = int(sender[key])
        if max < value: 
#(TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int' happens here)
            max = value

print(sender, max)
```

When I run each part of the code separatly it works, but together this traceback comes. Why the problem persists if I had turned variables 'max' and 'value' into integers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about what `max` is if the `max == None` check is false. Print it out before the error happens.

Comment: Because `max` is a built in function  when `max == None` is false its never overwritten. So thats why you get the error because your trying to compare the built in function `max` to a integer value

Answer (score 1):

You use `max` with `key` parameter.

```
max(sender,key=lambda x:sender[x])
#'zqian@umich.edu'
```

About error part in your for loop

`max` is a builtin

```
>>> max
<function max>
```

`if max==None:` is always false. So, it jumps to `else` part which is

```
else:
    value = int(sender[key])
    if max < value:
```

---

```
>>> max < 2
#TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

> Use variable names which don't collide with builtins and keywords.